# QThread confusion

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I'm using **Qt 4.7.0 (32 bit)** on **Windows 7 Ultimate (32 bit)** machine. I've been using Qt probably from version 4.0 or 4.2 and I've used almost all **4.x.y** releases.

Recently, with Qt 4.7 I've faced trouble.

I've written a multithreaded application in some older version of Qt. I've forgotten the version but probably the last version where I compiled and ran properly is 4.5.x or 4.6.x. The *threaded* part doesn't seem to be working correctly in 4.7, or I misunderstood something. Here is the problem:

The main thread starts `thinker` thread. Following is the `run()` function of `thinker` thread:

```
void ThinkerThread::run()
{
    _threads_running = NSUBTHINKERS;

    // ...
    _sub_thinker[0].start();

    // ...    
    _sub_thinker[1].start();

    exec();
}
```

The `_sub_thinker`'s `finished()` signal is connected with `ThinkerThread::subThinkerFinished()` slot for all `_sub_thinker`s. When all `_sub_thinker`s finish, `ThinkerThread::subThinkerFinished()` calls `quit()`.

There is another place where `quit()` is called:

```
void ThinkerThread::tryKill()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NSUBTHINKERS; i++)
        _sub_thinker[i].tryKill();
    quit();
}
```

From main thread, the execution is like as follows:

- thinker.tryKill() [Note: On very fist run, thinker wasn't running.]
- thinker.start()

`thinker`'s `finished()` signal is connected with `autoMove()`.

For all previous versions of Qt, `autoMove()` was called after `thinker::quit()` is called from `ThinkerThread::subThinkerFinished()`. In 4.7 I'm seeing that `autoMove()` is called after the very first call of `thinker.tryKill()`, even though the thread wasn't running.

Any idea?

Of course I can check inside `ThinkerThread::tryKill()` if `thinker` is running or not. But I'd like to know why is this happening.

Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed a problem with an app that worked fine on 4.2-4.6 and it dies in 4.7. Like yours the problem appears with threading. In particular for me when I call .start(). If I find anything I'll post back here (unless someone else has solved it by then). BTW, my issue occurs on 64bit Linux, so I suspect something in the core threading libs changed. Have you run it under a debugger or put some debug code in to see the value in NSUBTHINKERS?

Comment: NSUBTHINKERS is #defined to be 2. The change I'm seeing is with each quit() call, finished() is emitted. My code assumes that finished() will only be emitted by quit() if the thread is running - which happened with previous versions of Qt.

Comment: @ The Real Bill, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that `QThread::finished()` is emitted every time `QThread::quit()` is called irrespective of the state of `QThread` (i.e., running/not running). It didn't the case for previous versions of Qt.